# Unit Testing rich Views for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, nunit

If I have a rich AJAX-driven GUI in ASP.NET MVC, how would I unit test that effectively using a framework like NUnit?

Comment: I think he meant to say he wants to test the functions which are called through the ajax call, not exactly the UI. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Purely the client-side stuff.  I'm always on the fence on where testing starts and ends.  It seems like most things are geared towards controller-based testing with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to test the functionality of the UI, use browser automation tools like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) has a unit testing project called [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) which you could use to test your ajax code from a client.  It isn't going to integrate with NUnit, but it is another option.

Answer (score 1):

With NUnit, you would primarily be testing your controller actions -- i.e., given a set of parameters and a configuration, does the method return the correct result and view model.  If you need to test your client-side javascript, you should look at either a javascript unit testing framework or a UI testing tool, such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) to record tests and the generate NUnit testcases to verify behaviour and output of your views.

Steve Sanderson also blogged earlier on today about [HtmlUnit on .NET](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/) as 'headless browser'. (Testing using the Selenium server can be slow, because it requires creating an instance of FireFox, IE etc);

Answer (score 1):

You would have to unit test your ajax calls and not your UI per se., For example if you are getting some json data through a ajax call, this would translate to a controller method which can be unit tested.

I you want to unit test something which happens after the data reaches the browser then its a whole different ball game and not related to MVC.